# How do I upgrade my Azure Wordpress + MySQL Ubuntu 16.04 docker from PHP5.6 to PHP7?

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to Azure and docker/VM in general. I've just installed the following docker image on a S1 Azure VM, and I'm highly interested in upgrading the underlying PHP5.6 version to 7. I couldn't find much information online and it seems that the first step is I need to SSH into Docker and then perhaps execute some commands.

The docker image:
https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/Docker.wordpressplusmysql-ARM

My wordpress is of 4.7.2 latest version. What are the steps needed for me to be able to execute update commands inside Ubuntu? Thanks!

Comment: First check if your wordpress version is compliant with the new php version, and then you can either update your php using apt-get update or uninstalling php and install the new 7 version...also check if your apache version support php 7

Comment: You use the term 'perhaps execute some commands', I'd be worried.   Find a prebaked php7/wp container and set it up again.

Comment: Hackerman's approach to updating is correct for a bare-metal install.  For a docker container... not even remotely close to the 'docker way'.    You should be updating the image, not inside the container.   Once you do it inside the container -- you cannot recreate it via docker.

Comment: @user2105103 I'm inside the VM after sshing into it, with `docker images` it shows wordpress and mysql. How should I update the images without loss of data or causing some other troubles? Thanks!

Comment: You need to find a suitable image or roll your own, pull it down and set it up.   Way beyond the scope of 1 question.